# Changing filenames dynamically at set sizes / retina or not with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I'd like to understand how to alter some filenames of images via jQuery

On none retina devices

So I would like example.jpg to become example_mobile.jpg at screensizes of 400px and less and then when more than 401px become example.jpg once more

On retina devices

I would like example.jpg to become example_mobile@2x.jpg at screensies of 400px and less and then when mode than 401px become example@2x.jpg

How can I do this? The original filename source is example.jpg

I am also using retinaJS to automatically add @2x to the retina versions of example.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in javascript by testing the width of the `window` object :

```
if ($(window).width < 400) {
    var $img = $('#my_image');
    $img.attr('src', 'example_' + $img.attr('src'));
}
```

If you want to detect a retina device, you'll have to test the `navigator` object.

But the common way to do this is to use media queries and CSS.

Comment: Thanks - I do not follow the logic of your code past the window size detection though... looks like you are setting the src of the #my_image element in a var - then not sure???